# Error downloading dependencies while using upload component in python

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to run the code given here https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/upload to create an application which allows me to upload a Csv/Xlsx file in Dash. Upon running the code using terminal, there is 'Error downloading dependencies' error in Chrome.

This is the display in the terminal
[image]

I am new to Dash and not sure what this means and how it can be resolved.

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact error message? Complete traceback if available

Answer (score 0):

Could an ad blocker be causing the problem?

Try with adblockers disabled.